# Regular Expressions Ignore Case in search but not replace

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I want to be able to generically replace text, ignoring case in the search but not in the replace (kind of?).  Here is an example:

I have a list that looks like this:

Site -> Place

Stuff -> Things

etc...

Then I want to call ConvertMyString("Site") and have it return "Place".

So far I have this working, BUT...

If I call ConvertMyString("site"), I would like it to return "place" (lowercase).

Is there an easy way to do this with a RegEx or something without having to put all uppercase and lowercase versions in the list?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't get the regex result and then do a ToLowerCase?

Comment: Because I'm actually passing a sentence ("This is my site" and "Stuff for me is GREAT") and just replacing 1 word in the sentence.  I can't ToLower() the whole sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) to manipulate the replacement string? It gets handed the matched string so you could look at the case of that and assemble a replacement. Seemsa bit overkill, though

Answer (score 0):

or use this online tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/